# Set CPU options on Elastic Beanstalk environment via Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudformation

I have an Elastic Beanstalk worker app that is doing some memory-intensive single-threaded computation. <s>All the available instance types that meet my memory requirements (16 Gb) have 2+ vCPUs, so I only hit 50% CPU usage.</s> **Edit:** [This is just a quirk of how CPU usage is reported when hyperthreading is enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1460842/does-disabled-hyperthreading-double-the-performance-on-single-thread)

I see that on the instance types I'm interested in, I should be able to disable hyper-threading by setting the [ThreadsPerCore CPU option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance-cpuoptions.html) to 1, giving me a [free performance boost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html), but Elastic Beanstalk doesn't seem to provide a way to set this in it's [standard settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html).

The docs have plenty of examples of how to add custom resources using [cloud formation in .ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html). They also allude to the fact that the standard resources created by EB [can be modified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html); but I couldn't find any examples of this in practice. Having not used cloud formation before, I'm struggling to put the pieces together!

**Update:** Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51783555/6282033), it looked like I could just "redeclare" the EB resources and override the config, so I tried the following in an .ebextensions .config file:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBEC2LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        CpuOptions:
          ThreadsPerCore: 1
```

This feels like it gets me closer, but now when I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, I get the following error: `InvalidParameterValue: Both EC2 Launch Template and AS Launch Configuration exist in the template.` No results on Google for that one.

This seems like it might be a reference to the fact that an autoscaling group uses either a launch template, or a lauch configuration, but not both; but I haven't touched the scaling group, and when I look at the resources that EB creates as standard, there is no launch configuration, only a launch template.

Comment: My reading of non-authoritative sources suggests you might get 2-4% improvement in speed in a single threaded workload, but don't forget the operating system and other processes will benefit from having a second core available. In short, you may not get any speed-up from this, and if you do it will probably be a very small benefit. You'd probably be better off using a more suitable instance size.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I tried benchmarking manually on an instance with hyper-threading disabled. In the AWS console (and looking at `top`) total CPU usage went up to 100% from 50%, but I actually saw no performance gain whatsoever. I didn't realize the 50% was just a quirk of how CPU usage is reported when hyperthreading is enabled. I guess I'll leave the question up for now as editing CPU options via EB still seems like a valid question, even if it doesn't apply to my situation any more.

Comment: Indeed, whan you have e.g. 4 cores (whether 'real' or hyperthreading it's irrelevant) your CPU usage will max out at 400%, not 100%.